# How to implement Locking rows in a Spanner DB table with multiple applications of the service without making the service slow?

Tags: java, locking, race-condition, google-cloud-spanner

My service is interacting with spanner DB and one of the things my service tracks is booking cancellation. In the Spanner DB table, one row contains information on the order item. Let's say its quantity says a certain item was purchased in 4 quantities. One cancellation request is received by the service to cancel 2 qty of the item out of 4. The system creates a cancellation record for -2. Since the items were purchased in 4 qty and just is being cancelled, it's a partial cancellation. if you sum up all the inventory transaction records for that active qty should be 2. The problem occurs when two people are trying to do this at the same time. Say one person wants to cancel 2 qty another one also wants to cancel 2. If all 4 are cancelled Active qty should be 0 and the table should have another entry that, a particular order is cancelled. But as 2 threads are coming parallelly and reading the table history at the same time they both think it's a partial cancellation and the table is never updated with a cancelled entry as the active quantity is still 2.

Also, this service has multiple applications running on multiple pods.
what would be the best way to handle the race condition in Spanner DB given the above circumstances? Service is in Java Springboot.

I thought of using transactions with Spanner DB for locking up rows related to the same Order. But not able to get how it can be handled with multiple applications running on different pods.

Comment: Your problem is very simple to solve and is common to all SQL databases. Use transactions. I also recommend learning the basics of how databases work.

Comment: Not sure this is a transactions thing. If both users are legit, the database should honor both requests. Question is why would you have 2 different users issue the same order reduction request? How does this actually play out in reality? It is very different from a single user hitting the submit button twice or more. If you really have 2 different users submitting 2 different order change requests, both SHOULD complete successfully; each is an independent transaction. Please update your question to clarify your actual scenario.